# Check multiple columns for validity

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this a legitimate/good way of checking multiple column values in a row (in order to send to the user the appropriate feedback)?

```
select
    (date_expires < now()) as expired,
    (date_deleted is not null) as active 
  from sometable where row='foo';
```

It seems awfully convenient to me (this way I can make one query and conditionally alert the user to what exactly is wrong with the row they are trying to access), but I actually haven't seen it very much so I'm worried there is a big downside that I'm not seeing. Thanks!

Comment: This is perfectly fine, I do things like this all the time. Some people prefer to be explicit and use `CASE` -- I think that may be more portable to other DBMSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works, it's just going to give back separate columns.   If you want one column to hold the result, then it's some case statement fun.

```
select
case when date_expires < now() then 'Inactive'
else 'active'
end as status
from sometable where row='foo';
```

That would give you status with inactive/active as it's two values.  I just went with else active, you can put in a series of when this condition then 'this value' if you wanted.

Comment: You're only checking `date_expires`, not `date_deleted`.

Comment: figured the else covered that condition, but you are right